# KAFKA Group Coordinator Fail Recovery on 0.11.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any configuration to enable automatic group coordinator recovery after a crash?

I have a testing topology with 3 brokers and once the Group Coordinator is shutdown, the topic partitions (2 partitions with rf=2) gets correctly re balanced, the producer is not affected, but the consumer group stop receiving messages. If I choose any other broker everything works as expected.

Using the JAVA API Kafka Clients 0.10.2.1 for producer and client

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
   <version>0.10.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Monitoring the console output of each broker that remains running, I don't find any reference of a new GroupCoordinator assignment. All consumers resume receiving messages as soon I start the original group coordinator broker. The broker elected as coordinator is always the broker.id=0, no matter the startup order.

Client Config:

```
private static Consumer<String, String> createFixMessageConsumer(int id) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "6100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, MYCONSUMERGROUP);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, id + "");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());     
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        return new KafkaConsumer<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new FixMessageDeserializer());
    }
```

Consumer Worker snippet:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            consumer.subscribe(topics);

            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, FixMessage> records = consumer.poll(2000);
                FixMessage message = null;
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, FixMessage> record : records) {
                    message = record.value();
                    message.setConsumerId(id);
                    message.setKafkaPartition(record.partition());
                    message.setPartitionOffset(BigInteger.valueOf(record.offset()));
                    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("partition", record.partition());
                    data.put("offset", record.offset());
                    if(message.getIdfixMessage() == null)
                        createFixMessage(message, data);
                    data.put("value", message.getIdfixMessage());
                    System.out.println(this.id + ": " + data);
                }
            }
      } catch (WakeupException e) {
        // ignore for shutdown 
      } catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.toString());
      } finally {
        consumer.close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: You could check the replication factor of topic `__consumer_offsets` to see if it's 1

Comment: You are right @amethystic! Once I increase the RF for the __consumer_offsets topic the Group Coordinator Failure recovery happens as expected. Please submit an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure the replication factor of topic `__consumer_offsets` is greater than 1 in your case. Before 0.11.0.0, broker-side parameter `default.replication.factor` will not be enforced, so it's very likely the rf of this internal topic is less than `default.replication.factor` you set.

Comment: My god. This was our case as well. Isn't this dangerous? __consumer_offsets topic is so important and it doesn't have sufficient replication factor!

Comment: doesn't help, just another WARN messages are logged on the consumer side: "Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available."

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with Kafka 2.11-1.0.0. That is , while consumption , if the broker where the consumer group coordinator resides shuts down, new coordinator was not getting discovered. As a result, message consumption was totally halted, inspite of producer being able to continually produce to the newly elected leader (Newly elected leader was in picture, as one of the partitions was falling on the shutdown broker, but it got auto-reassigned to one of the ISRs). After updating the replication factor of internal topic `__consumer_offsets` to 3 (I have a cluster of 3 brokers), automatic failover of consumer group coordinator started happening. All messages that were successfully produced got consumed after auto discovery of the new consumer group coordinator. To increase RF for internal topic `__consumer_offsets` , refer to : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor

Comment: We suffered this same problem in our backup cluster. Our primary cluster is having __consumer_offsets RF as 3 however backup cluster only had 1. I don't know it was more on primary. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: @Shades88 - your backup cluster has RF of 1 set for the internal topic '__consumer_offsets' ? If yes, you need to increase the RF of the '__consumer_offsets ' topic appropriately (in proportion to the number of brokers you have in your backup cluster)

Comment: doesn't help, just another WARN messages are logged on the consumer side: "Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available."